# Error with ToString()

Tags: c, tostring

I'm new to c. Please help me

Why do I get this error using eclipse

```
Multiple markers at this line
- request for member 'ToString' in something not a structure or union
- Method 'ToString' could not be resolved
```

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int s = 5;
    int n = 4;
    char g = s.ToString();
    char l = n.ToString();
    printf(g+l);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `#c`? That's not a thing.

Comment: C and C# are two different languages. There isn't a `ToString()` method for fundamental types. Even if there was, you wouldn't assign it to a `char`.

Comment: @EdCottrell I mean C language sorry I'm new

Comment: @remyabel Sorry; So is there any way to convert int to string in C

Comment: @elti musa To convert `int` to string 1) create `char` array _at least_ large enough to hold all the characters and the terminating `'\0'`, 2) convert.  `char str[100]; sprintf(str, "%d", some_int);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s` and `n` are just `int`s; they don't have a `ToString()` method. Also, as @remyabel pointed out, `char` is not the appropriate type for storing a string value, anyway; it stores only one character.

You don't need to convert your `int`s to strings at all to do what you're trying to accomplish, so you actually want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int s = 5;
    int n = 4;

    printf("%d%d", s, n); // you can't add l to g here!

    return 0;
}
// output 54
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/WXOIWb)

Oh, and *please* use more descriptive variable names!

**EDIT:** To save the string, as requested in the comments, you could do this:

```
char myString[10];
sprintf(myString, "%d%d", s, n); // myString is now "54"
```

Comment: @leppie Yeah, that's wrong; it was in the OP's original code. I fixed it.

Comment: @remyabel An `int` is an object in plain old c (not c++, c#, etc.)? If so, that's news to me, and I would really appreciate a link. My c skills are a little rusty. As for the `printf` line, you're right; already fixed.

Comment: @remyabel I want output to be 54 not 6; THANKS ANYWAY

Comment: @eltimusa I misread your original post; see the edited version.

Comment: @EdCottrell the word "object" doesn't have the same meaning in C as in object-oriented languages. Here it basically means "thing".

Comment: @remyabel Fair enough; I didn't realize the standard used that terminology. I edited to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @remyabel is there any way to create a new string with value of 54 because i don't need to printf it but to use it for some other action;

Comment: @eltimusa See my edit; you want the `sprintf` function.

Comment: Hope you aren't planning on using this code for numbers that are longer than 9 digits together.

Comment: @nemetroid Yes, good point; I'm just trying to help OP get going. Obviously, this isn't production-ready code (or particularly useful).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest picking up a C tutorial and starting from the beginning. The use of `ToString` isn't the only thing that's wrong. You could rewrite it this way and it should work (assuming you want to print "54"):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int s = 5;
    int n = 4;
    char g = '0' + s;
    char l = '0' + n;
    printf("%c%c", g, l);

    return 0;
}
```

But this only works as long as `s` and `n` are less than 10, and besides is overly complicated since `printf` is made for formatting and printing values of different types. This would work just as well:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int s = 5;
    int n = 4;
    printf("%d%d", s, n);

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to use the string for something else than printing, the answer depends on what you want to do.